# Porting AES Java decipher code to Node.js

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I've got the following Java code that I'd like to port to Node.js:

```
// Java

byte[] rawKey = "deadbeefdeadbeef".getBytes("us-ascii");
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES");
Cipher cip = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
cip.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
byte[] plaintext = cip.doFinal(ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.length);
```

Here's my attempt with Node.js, using streams

```
// JS, using the crypto streams API

var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-ecb', 'deadbeefdeadbeef');
decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
decipher.pipe(concat(function(plaintext) { console.log(plaintext); });
decipher.end(ciphertext);
```

And, also a Node.js attempt using the older `.update()` and `.final()` API:

```
// JS, using the `.update()` and `.final()` API

var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-ecb', 'deadbeefdeadbeef');
decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
var pieces = [];
pieces.push(new Buffer(decipher.update(ciphertext)));
pieces.push(new Buffer(decipher.final()));
var plaintext = Buffer.concat(pieces);
```

Both of these versions produce the same output of the correct length (the same length as the input), but this output is not the same plaintext that is produced by the Java version of the decipher operating on the same input buffer. How can I set up a Node.js decipher like the Java decipher configured above?

Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be using AES-128 in the Java code while you specify AES-256 in the JS code. I'm not sure how the JS API can accept a 128-bit key for a 256-bit cipher; perhaps it's performing some sort of key derivation?

Comment: My bad, that was a copy/paste from old code! Thank you for pointing it out. I had figured out as much around the time of posting this question. I've since had this problem solved, and will post an answer soon. Though, I'm not versed in crypto and don't understand the meaning of the answer: using `crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-ecb', 'deadbeefdeadbeef', '');` did the trick.

Comment: @ntoskrnl: And yes, for a while I was using `aes-256-ecb` with a 128-bit key and it wasn't throwing or indicating error otherwise. Just producing undesired decrypt output.

Comment: @dimadima As your ciphertext is not protected for integrity nor authenticity, your ciphertext will happily decrypt to random bytes. Normally this is caught by the unpadding (which can have disastrous results itself because of padding oracle attacks) but otherwise the output is simply random. You can even decrypt with DES and get a result. Add a MAC or HMAC to protect against such things (and do use CBC and padding, your current solution is probably insecure on many levels).

Comment: What is the `concat` function in `decipher.pipe(concat(...`?

Comment: @justin.m.chase it's https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat-stream, used in this case for debug logging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`createDecipher`](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipher_algorithm_password) actually does not use a key as you do in Java. It uses a password, which is fed into a Password Based Key Derivation Function (PBKDF) to *derive* the key. Hence with a different key and no method of checking the correctness of the key, you will get random plain text.

The Node.js API is not very well named, the functions `createDecipher` and `createDecipheriv` suggest that the latter is just the same as the former, with the addition of an IV. Instead, `createDecipher` adds an entire key derivation function to the mix.

Comment: @dimadima Answered it for you, if you don't mind, as I do know why this made such a big difference. Please indicate if you made additional changes to your code to make this work.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, changing to the IV function was all that was necessary. To be specific: `crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-ecb', 'deadbeefdeadbeef')` -> `crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-ecb', 'deadbeefdeadbeef', '')`

Comment: With v0.10.35 node always throws the error "node-crypto : Invalid IV length " if I use the proposed solution - any workaround?

Comment: @Skomski Try `crypto.randomBytes(size)` to create the IV, make sure you understand the way NodeJS handles buffers and streaming. The IV can be prefixed to the ciphertext.